# Show that there exists a conjugate $\gamma$ of $\beta$ in $A_n$ such that $\beta\circ \gamma$ is a $3$-cycle.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $\beta$ be the product of two disjoint $3$-cycles in alternating group $A_n$. Show that there exists a conjugate $\gamma$ of $\beta$ in $A_n$ such that $\beta\circ\gamma$ (where $\circ$ denotes composition of permutations) is a $3$-cycle.

I'm not sure how to go about finding a $\gamma$ such that this will work. How do I go about starting this?

Comment: Well, for starters, you might as well just consider $A_6$ and let $\beta$ be $(1 2 3) (4 5 6)$; can you see how any other choice is isomorphic to this?  Now, what does $\gamma$ being conjugate to $\beta$ imply about its cycle structure?

Comment: $\gamma$ conjugate to $\beta$ means there exists a $\tau$ such that $\gamma = \tau \beta \tau^{-1}$. I'm not sure does need to be $ \in A_n$. Or how to find $\tau$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\beta = \beta_1\beta_2$ and then $\gamma=\beta_1\beta_2^{-1}$.

Check that they are conjugate in $A_n$ and $\beta\circ\gamma$ is a $3$-cycle.